# How to check that the ID is not duplicated in ASP MVC and EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am developing an `ASP .Net MVC 3`application using `C# and SQL Server 2005`.

I am using also Entity Framework and Code First Method.

I have a model `Poste` related to a table `Poste` in my base.

**When I want to add a new poste, I would like that its ID 'Primary Key' will be checked in order to not be duplicate and produice an Exception.**

I try to use `Remote` but there is some problems.

This is what I try :

Model :

```
public class Poste
    {
        [Required]
        [Key]
        [Display(Name = "ID Poste :")]
        [Remote("PosteExists", "Poste", "ID is already taken.")]
        public string ID_Poste { get; set; }
```

In the Controller 'PosteController' :

```
public JsonResult PosteExists(string poste)
        {
            var p = _repository.GetPosteByName(poste.Trim());
            return p == null ?
                Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet) :
                Json(string.Format("{0} is not available.", poste),
                    JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

First, `_repository` does not exist in the current Context.

Second, I don't is this solution will be check the values from the base.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to check whether it is used or not. Just define a primary key of type integer and it will be auto incremented in database for each record inserted.

```
public int PosteID { get; set; }
```

By convention `PosteID` will become the primary key of table `Poste`.

Comment: thx but I don't want that it will be auto incremented. It' s a sort of string values that I have to enter like a Zip Code of electronic card or something like that

Answer (score 0):

You have db access in that controller, so you can check against that.

```
public JsonResult PosteExists(string poste)
{
    var exists = db.Postes.Any(x => x.ID_Poste == poste.Trim())
    return !exists ?
        Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet) :
        Json(string.Format("{0} is not available.", poste),
        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Assuming `ID_Poste` is what you're checking against.

Comment: THX colm, but after trying this code, when i click in the button to submit the create, the page is refreshing without any modification. Even the values still written in the fields!

Comment: Can you add to the question the code that calls `PosteExists`

Comment: I already put it : [Remote("PosteExists", "Poste", "ID is already taken.")]

Comment: To clarify more the situation :

I put a breakpoint in the controller method 'PosteExists' and when I debug, I can't hit it.

So, 

`[Required]
[Key]
[Display(Name = "ID Poste :")]
[Remote("PosteExists", "Poste", "Username is already taken.")]
public string ID_Poste { get; set; }`
I think that

`[Remote("PosteExists", "Poste", "Username is already taken.")]` 
 can't reach the controller.

Answer (score 0):

The remote attribute will work fine. Where did you get your _repository code from? Why can't you create an instance in your controller?

Also be aware that the Remote attribute doesn't validate when you post the form back to the action method, you will need to validate it again on the server side.

Comment: thx Adam, Where did you get your _repository code from? ==> Really I don't know where, I think it is from a library or somethin like this
Why can't you create an instance in your controller? ==> Is that necessary ?

Comment: ya, you are referencing a _repository class so that snippet of code assumes this class was created so you'll need it. You could just create a new context in that method but what you have above uses whats known as the repository pattern and assumes there's a class called something like PosteRepository (typically thats what it would be named). You could instantiate your context directly in there and query it - that would be the easiest although not necessarily the most testable approach - if you wanted to write tests.

Comment: Let's forget the repository,,, I tried the solution of colm,,and when I submit,,the page reload it and nothing change as I said in my comment

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Did you include the right js libs? Does your method ever get called prior to post? As I said it won't get called on the server side form post to controller method, but when you are in that field on the page.

Comment: Did you include the right js libs?==> No and I don't find how
Does your method ever get called prior to post? ==> No
About my comment, I said that I tried it the answer above

Comment: To clarify more the situation : I put a breakpoint in the controller method 'PosteExists' and when I debug, I can't hit it. So, [Required] [Key] [Display(Name = "ID Poste :")] [Remote("PosteExists", "Poste", "Username is already taken.")] public string ID_Poste { get; set; } I think that [Remote("PosteExists", "Poste", "Username is already taken.")] can't reach the controller.

Comment: You can test this in the browser by simply going to localhost/controller/PosteExists?poste=test (or whatever your controller name is and local web server port). If it DOES get hit, then its likely a script include issue. If it doesnt get hit, its a routing issue.

Comment: ohours.org/adamtuliper if you cant get this resolved book a time with me tomorrow (its free) and we'll look at it and then post solution here.

Comment: thx,,,when i did what you told me : i have a white page where is written : true

Comment: I think I know your issue, lets chat in the AM (I saw the request come in)